# Rails backend with React Native

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a React Native mobile marketplace app with Rails as backend.
Buyers are able to sign up both via mobile and web, sellers too.

When the buyers want to buy, seller receive an email notification and a PUSH notification mobile.

I want to know which is the best strategy to get only the sellers that download the app so only they receive the push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm). It's a module that lets you connect with Google's firebase cloud messaging. From there, you can send a push notification to a specific user using their unique token.

To get that token, you must create a different API function that will receive the token when the user registers a new account.

For example:

```
FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
    console.log(token)
    // call the registeration api here
});
```